# Blender as Python module in Docker container: How to build CUDA kernels only once?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, gpu, compile

I'm building a docker image (multi-stage) with Blender built as a Python module and CUDA support:

```
###########################################
# Stage 1: Build Blender as a Python module
###########################################

FROM nvidia/cudagl:11.4.2-devel-ubuntu20.04 as bpy-builder

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG BLENDER_VERSION="v3.0.0"
ARG BLENDER_LIBRARY_VERSION="3.0"

# Update and upgrade packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Basic requirements (see https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu#Quick_Setup)
RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    subversion \
    cmake \
    libx11-dev \
    libxxf86vm-dev \
    libxcursor-dev \
    libxi-dev \
    libxrandr-dev \
    libxinerama-dev \
    libglew-dev 

# # Wayland requirements (see https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu#Quick_Setup)
# RUN apt-get install -y \
#     libwayland-dev \
#     wayland-protocols \
#     libegl-dev \
#     libxkbcommon-dev \
#     libdbus-1-dev \
#     linux-libc-dev

# Python requirements
RUN apt-get install -y \
    python3.9 \
    python3.9-dev \
    python3-distutils \
    python3-pip \
    python3-apt

# Clone a shallow copy of the blender sources
RUN mkdir -p /opt/blender-git/
WORKDIR /opt/blender-git/
RUN git clone https://github.com/blender/blender.git -c advice.detachedHead=false --depth 1 --branch ${BLENDER_VERSION}
WORKDIR /opt/blender-git/blender
RUN git checkout -b my-branch

## Checkout submodules
RUN git submodule foreach git checkout ${BLENDER_VERSION}

# Download a copy of the blender libraries
RUN mkdir -p /opt/blender-git/lib
WORKDIR /opt/blender-git/lib
RUN svn export https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/tags/blender-${BLENDER_LIBRARY_VERSION}-release/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/

# Set build flags
## Python
ARG WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF
ARG WITH_AUDASPACE=OFF
ARG WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON

## GPU
ARG WITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_CUDA=ON
ARG WITH_CYCLES_CUDA_BINARIES=ON

# Compile blender
WORKDIR /opt/blender-git/blender
RUN make update
RUN make bpy


###########################################
# Stage 2: Slim image for deployment
###########################################

# TODO: See if we can use a smaller image (e.g. by installing CUDA separately).
FROM nvidia/cudagl:11.4.2-devel-ubuntu20.04  


ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG USER_NAME=user

# Update and upgrade packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Install development dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y \
    git

# Install Python 3.9
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    python3.9 \
    python3.9-dev \
    python3-distutils \
    python3-pip \
    python3-apt

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 10
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 10

# Copy blender python module
COPY --from=bpy-builder /opt/blender-git/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages \
    /opt/bpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/bpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages"

COPY --from=bpy-builder /opt/blender-git/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages \
    /opt/bpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages

# Install blender dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libgomp1 \
    libxrender1

# Install other dependencies
# RUN apt-get install -y \
#     

# Add a non-root user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ${USER_NAME}
USER ${USER_NAME}
WORKDIR /home/${USER_NAME}
```

Everything works well, however, when starting the container and rendering an image with cycles and CUDA I get the following message:

```
Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)
Compiling CUDA kernel ...
"/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc" -arch=sm_86 --cubin "/opt/bpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/3.0/scripts/addons/cycles/source/kernel/device/cuda/kernel.cu" -o "/home/user/.cache/cycles/kernels/cycles_kernel_sm_86_79FDBA777FBD1427AA019FCC8B5AFBF6.cubin" -m64 --ptxas-options="-v" --use_fast_math -DNVCC -I"/opt/bpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/3.0/scripts/addons/cycles/source"
```

This would be no problem, however, due to the nature of docker, as soon as I restart the container, I have to build the kernels again.

So my question is: What is the best way to avoid having to compile the kernels on the first run?

Thoughts/ideas:

1. Maybe I missed a compilation flag (I thought this is what `WITH_CYCLES_CUDA_BINARIES` is for)?
2. So, maybe I didn't copy over the already compiled files from the building part of the multi-stage Dockerfile? If so, then where can I find the compiled kernels?
3. I can trigger the build myself using the command from the message. However, it includes `-arch=sm_86`, so I guess this is specific for the Hardware I'm using, right? So I would have to trigger this for all architectures supported by blender (`sm_30 sm_35 sm_37 sm_50 sm_52 sm_60 sm_61 sm_70 sm_75 sm_86 compute_75`, see [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)), correct?
4. I could map `/home/user/.cache` to the respective directory on the host, however, this seems a little hacky and cumbersome. Also, it would be great to just compile the kernels once during the docker build, instead of once for every user.

EDIT: Solution 4 works, but I'd still appreciate a more elegant solution.